# Grails render a loading page while retrieving data

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have a web application that takes a while to load up the initial page.  The main screen has a lot of data with multiple datasources, thus the load time is longer than I would like.

I would like to have a splash screen rendered immediately, while the controller continues to get the data for the page.

My controller pseudo code would look like this ( I know having the render twice will not work but this is what I would like to have happen) :

```
  def index() {
          render view: 'MyTempView'
          methods to go get data
          render view: 'expectedView' model: [all my data]
  }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can show the splash screen and get the data with ajax. When the ajax call is back with data/html you just hide the splash div and show the data

Comment: @OfirW that is what I have ended up doing.  I wish there were a better built in way to do this in Grails, however this will work.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know any other option to achieve it, maybe on next versions of grails ;-). I posted an answer please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the splash screen and get the data with ajax. When the ajax call is back with data/html you just hide the splash div and show the data.